# Grab end of URL before GET $_parameters

Tags: php, arrays, url

I'm having an issue with grabbing the last part of the URL before the query parameters.
The current solution I'm using is this:

```
$base_url = current_url();
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
$language = $uri_segments[1];
$end_url = array_pop($uri_segments);
```

I then pass the $end_url through a Switch statement to modify form fields, depending on the value.
Is there something I'm missing or is there a more efficient way to grab the last part of the URL?
Any suggestions would be helpful and greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You're exploding using `/` as the delimiter. So the query parameters will be included in the last element, since there's no `/` delimiter there.

Comment: You can use `explode('?', $end_url)` and then use the first element of that.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#120979 maybe you should be using one of the other `$_SERVER` variables, like `PHP_SELF` or `SCRIPT_NAME`. They don't include the query parameters.

Comment: `basename($uri_path)` - https://3v4l.org/pZT83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/project/controller/action/param1/param2');
$url['sections'] = explode('/', $url['path']);

$last = end($url['sections']);
echo $last;
?>
```

output

> param2